# I cannot get the html doc to load the javascript to make my calculator working

Tags: calculator

I've followed this calculator video on YouTube.  I have 3 files in a folder .html, .css & .js.
I open the calculator by double-clicking the HTML file which seems to load up fine in opera with the CSS changing the appearance, however the functionality of the buttons do not work at all. Now I have double-checked the code and even gone as far as cheating with the resource material to be sure it's not an error in the code. I feel that the JavaScript isn't being read/used at all when it loads up.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j59qQ7YWLxw

```
class calculator {
    constructor(perviousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
        this.perviousOperandTextElement = perviousOperandTextElement
        this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
        this.clear()
    }

    clear() {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.perviousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }

    delete() {
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString().slice(0, -1)
    }

    appendNumber(number) {
        if (number === '.' && this.currentOperand.includes('.')) return
        this.currentOperand = this.currentOperand.toString() + number.tostring()
    }

    chooseOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentOperand === '') return
        if (this.perviousOperand !== '') {
            this.compute()
        }
        this.operation = operation
        this.perviousOperand = this.currentOperand
        this.currentOperand = ''
    }

    compute() {
        let computation
        const prev = parseFloat(this.previousOperand)
        const current = parseFloat(this.currentOperand)
        if (isNaN(prev) || isNaN(current)) return
        switch (this.operation) {
            case'+':
                computation = prev + current
                break
            case '-':
                computation = prev - current
                break
            case '*':
                computation = prev * current
                break
            case '÷':
                computation = prev / current
                break
            default:
                return
        }
        this.currentOperand = computation
        this.operation = undefined
        this.perviousOperand = ''
    }

    getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString()
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0])
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1]
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
            integerDisplay = ''
        } else {
            integerDisplay integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
            return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`
        } else {
            return integerDisplay
        }
    }

    updateDisplay() {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = 
            this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentOperand)
        if (this.operation != null) {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = 
            `${this.getDisplayNumber(this.perviousOperand)} ${this.operation}`
        } else {
            this.previousOperandTextElement.innerText = ''  
        }
    }
}


const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        calculator.chooseOperation(button.innerText)
        calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})

equalsButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.compute()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

allClearButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    calculator.clear()
    calculator.updateDisplay()
})

deleteButton.addEventListener('click', button => {
calculator.delete()
calculator.updateDisplay()
})
```

Comment: Can you post your html code here? Thanks

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>

Comment: <script src="script.js" defer></script>

I believe that is the element thats meant to be included.?

Comment: The calculator seems to work fine for me. Did you put it in the same directory?

Comment: all 3 files are in the same folder. im really confused as to why the css is picked up but the javascript isnt executing.

Comment: Could you open developer tools and view the console to see if theres any errors?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier script.js:67

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code is wrong at line 67.
We can see that at line 67, your code writes

```js
integerDisplay integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
```

This is clearly wrong as you are missing a `=`, which assigns the value. A solution to this is to replace the line with

```js
integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 0 })
```

Comment: including the missing = worked for line 67 :) thank you.

now the developer tool gives a message..

Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'calculator' has already been declared. 97

I checked with the resource material on git hub and it copied and pasted the line in so its exact to be sure however same message occurs.

Comment: Look at your first line, it should be `Calculator` not `calculator`. By writing `calculator` instead of `Calculator`, you attempted to redeclare `calculator` in line 97.

Comment: you've helped me ALOT Thankyou. I'm getting the grips with this problem solving.

Comment: I now have numbers appearing but they're massive font and other crazy things :D

Comment: Is your CSS correct